# 404 в WebClient

Tags: c#

Решил написать программу, которая скачивает с YouTube миниатюры. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что иногда `WebClient` выкидывает ошибку 404.

Хотел сделать так, что если по выбраному качеству выдает ошибку 404, берем ссылку на более низкое качество картинки.

Но оно почему-то не работает.

```
public class Downloader
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    public void Download(string ide, string quality, string filename, string path)
    {
        if (path == @"C:\Downloads")
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Downloads");
        }
        string uri;
        if (quality == "maxresdefault")// В программе выбрано максимальное качество
        {
            string[] maxDef =
                {//от максимального (ide - идентификатор видео)
                    "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ide + "/maxresdefault.jpg",
                    "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ide + "/sddefault.jpg",
                    "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ide + "/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ide + "/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ide + "/default.jpg"
                //до минимального
                };

            foreach (var i in maxDef)//запихиваю массив в цикл
            {
                uri = i;//присваиваю максимальное, и по прохождению до минимального
//если присвоить ссылку которая действительная сразу - качает, из массива нет
                filename = path + "\\" + filename + ".jpg";//задаю путь и имя файла
                try
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(uri, filename);//пытаюсь скачать
                    break;//если скачало выхожу из цикла
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
```

Comment: Может сервера гугла вас футболят за слишком частые запросы?

Comment: Врятли, если загружаю файл со ссылками, и выбираю качество которое есть у всех картинок- скачивает и 200 и 500.

Comment: `...  иногда WebClient выкидывает ошибку 404.` На всякий случай спрошу, ошибка воспроизводится? Т.е. возникает случайным образом или стабильно на конкретных `ide`?

Comment: Она возникает, если  ссылка не существует, проверял в браузере.

Comment: Т.е. видео есть, а миниатюры по умолчанию (`http://img.youtube.com/vi/<ide>/default.jpg`) нет?

Comment: Нет, default есть. Суть в том, что коггда выбираю мах а его нет  , ошибка, перескакивает на сд - ошибка, хд есть, ошибки нет, и выходит из цикла, при этом не скачивая. а если в uri сразу поместить ссылку на hd - скачивает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перенесите `filename = path + "\\" + filename + ".jpg";` перед циклом `foreach (var i in maxDef)` и все заработает. У вас путь инкрементируется.

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!